# Update multiple fields in mysql by publishing single message to kafka

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, sql-update, apache-kafka-connect

I have an requirement to update status as De Active in Mysql 'Table1' for last 10 days records through kafka connect.
how would I achieve to publish one record to kafka topic because mysql provides to perform select and update in single query.

Comment: Provides = prevents?

Comment: in mysql select and update both are possible in single query right ?

Comment: In MySQL, it is not possible to execute a SELECT and UPDATE within a single query.

Comment: In MySQL you may create stored procedure which executes any amount of statements - from the client application side you will execute only one `CALL procname(parameters)` query.

Comment: inside update query we can specify select query right ?

Comment: I am updating status as D in table1 for last 10 days . in my table i have timestamp column, from that i will get last 10 days record only for those records i have to update status column

Comment: *inside update query we can specify select query right ?* Partially. You may use SELECT as a part of UPDATE - but you cannot return its rowset, it can be used in updating process only.

Comment: yes you are right akina. this what i have to send to kafka connect

Answer (score 0):

DEMO example.

> ```
> -- create stored procedure (once)
>
> CREATE PROCEDURE execute_many_queries (queries_text TEXT)
> BEGIN
> REPEAT
>     SET @sql := SUBSTRING_INDEX(queries_text, ';', 1);
>     SET queries_text := TRIM(LEADING ';' FROM TRIM(LEADING @sql FROM queries_text));
>     PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
>     EXECUTE stmt;
>     DROP PREPARE stmt;
> UNTIL queries_text = '' END REPEAT;
> END
> ```

> ```
> -- create testing table
>
> CREATE TABLE test (id INT, val INT);
> ```

> ```
> -- execute 3 queries by 1 statement
>
> CALL execute_many_queries ('INSERT INTO test VALUES (1,11), (2,22); UPDATE test SET val = 222 WHERE id = 2; SELECT * FROM test;');
> ```
>
> ```
> id | val
> -: | --:
>  1 |  11
>  2 | 222
> ```

> ```
> -- execute more 2 queries by 1 statement
>
> CALL execute_many_queries ('UPDATE test SET val = 111 WHERE id = 1; SELECT * FROM test;');
> ```
>
> ```
> id | val
> -: | --:
>  1 | 111
>  2 | 222
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4060eaf332f83e3c40101454573df571)*

Use with caution! no checks in SP - the queries must be error-free. And injection is possible.

Comment: Thank you for efforts.. Here you have called procedure to execute mysql queries instead i need this query to be executed through kafka connector

Comment: Kafka connector performs the queries by itself, not sends them as-is to MySQL? Sorry...

Comment: I just want to know whether its possible through kafka or not